# the yowsup library does not work when I try to register

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, yowsup

I installed the next packages in my raspberry with pip3:
-python-axolotl
-protobuf
-six
-argparse
-readline
-pillow
-tqdm
-requests
-pycrypto
-blinker

Next I installed yowsup with

pip3 install yowsup

So, I download a repository, https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework, (today is 2019-May-17), I live in Colombian, so I intent send the registration with:
yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 57317509xxx --cc 57 -E android

I installed the next packages in my raspberry with pip3:
-python-axolotl
-protobuf
-six
-argparse
-readline
-pillow
-tqdm
-requests
-yowsup
-pycrypto
-blinker

next, I download a repository, https://github.com/danielcardeenas/whatsapp-framework, (today is 2019-May-17), I live in Colombian, so I intent send the registration with:
yowsup-cli registration --requestcode sms --phone 57317509xxx --cc 57 -E android

but the console print a error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/yowsup-cli", line 4, in 
import('pkg_resources').run_script('yowsup2==2.5.2', 'yowsup-cli')
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 739, in run_script
self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/init.py", line 1494, in run_script
exec(code, namespace, namespace)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.2-py3.5.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 368, in 
if not parser.process():
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.2-py3.5.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 189, in process
self.handleRequestCode(self.args["requestcode"], config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup2-2.5.2-py3.5.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/yowsup-cli", line 198, in handleRequestCode
from yowsup.registration import WACodeRequest
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup/registration/init.py", line 1, in 
from .coderequest import WACodeRequest
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup/registration/coderequest.py", line 1, in 
from yowsup.common.http.warequest import WARequest
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup/common/http/init.py", line 2, in 
from .warequest import WARequest
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup/common/http/warequest.py", line 8, in 
from yowsup.common.tools import WATools
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yowsup/common/tools.py", line 10, in 
from consonance.structs.keypair import KeyPair
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/consonance/structs/keypair.py", line 4, in 
from dissononce.dh.x25519.x25519 import X25519DH
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/dissononce/dh/x25519/x25519.py", line 1, in 
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import x25519
ImportError: cannot import name 'x25519'

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue

The problem is not with yowsup, but with its dependencies (so it couldn't import: x25519) and concretely with the cryptography library.

The following commands might help you solve it but check while installing that dependencies are solved, because there seems to be a lot of them that have to be manually solved:

`pip3 install cryptography --force-reinstall`

`pip3 install yowsup --force-reinstall`

Other commands you may have to use to solve dependencies:

`pip3 install python-axolotl-curve25519`

`pip3 install six==1.10`

Hope to at least have pointed in the right direction!